# MapView loadListener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Is there a way to attach a loadListener to the MapView widget?

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:apiKey="my api key" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Java:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.  // attach listeners?
```

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288507/how-get-the-progress-status-of-loading-mapview-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a method that creates the listeners for the `MapView` that you want to attach after you create it, and just have it take the mapview to attach the listener to.

Something like

```
public void attachMapViewListeners (MapView mapView){
    //Attach your listeners here
}
```

Then just call that with the MapView that needs all of the listeners attached.

**Edit**

Now I get exactly what you are trying to do.

So you will want to listen for the `onFinishInflate()` Event.

More here if you want specifics 
[Android Dev View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all. I just want to know whether it's possible to add a loadListener or detect when the map is loaded. I've checked most of the mapView methods but can't find any relevant methods...

edit: this is really android specifik...

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about. Too bad the onFinishInflate method isn't provided in mapview

Comment: Your going to have to grab it for the whole Layout I think

Comment: I can get the whole layout by id. But also this one has no method to listen when it's loaded. Any other options?