# dismiss ProgressDialog after MapView has loaded

Tags: android

I want to show ProgressDialog while starting activity which initializes map automatically, and dismiss it when MapView is loaded to a certain measure. I don't want users to watch default gray screen before map is loaded. Is there a function which shows progress of map loading or similar indicator?

Thank You, 
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show a dialog like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress = (ProgressDialog) new ProgressDialog(context);
progress.isIndeterminate();
progress.setTitle("Map setup");
progress.setCancelable(false);
progress.setMessage("Wait a second while map is prepared");

progress.show();
```

Then you remove it like this:

```
progress.dismiss();
```

**Edit**

There is nothing like that for android maps. The closest thing is the mapview methode `canCoverCenter()`

A similar post with same response is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288507/969325).

But the tiles is not the only thing that takes time loading, if you have a lot of overlays it might take time to load them and in that case I might be able to understand the progressbar. But if the only issue is with the grey tiles I wouldn't recommend this kind of behavior. If you look at googles own map implementations (Latitude, navigation, maps) they all have grey tiles before loading the correct tiles. This is the intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't thing i was looking for... I know how to dismiss dialog but real question is WHEN to call dismiss function. I need to know is MapView loaded enough to show some map, even if it's still little blurry.

Comment: @Filip Added new answer about your possibilities.

Comment: Ok. At least I realised there's no such a thing. Thanks.